# It's taking two calls to /oauth/dialog/ to get an access_token?

Tags: support, bug, api

When we send this request:

```
https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog/?client_id=`client_id`&scope=read_inbox%2cno_expiry%2cwrite_access%2cprivate_info&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fstackexchange.com%2foauth%2flogin_success
```

the page gets redirected to `http://stackexchange.com/`

Again when we send this request to:

```
https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog/?client_id=`client_id`&scope=read_inbox%2cno_expiry%2cwrite_access%2cprivate_info&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fstackexchange.com%2foauth%2flogin_success
```

then we get:

```
https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success#access_token=`access_token`
```

---

Isn't this wrong? We should be getting:

```
https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success#access_token=`access_token`
```

on the first request itself.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is Insufficient information to duplicate the problem.  It needs an MCVE.

Comment: Kindly ask for more information where it is not clear. This question was edited by http://stackapps.com/users/26088/%E1%94%95%E1%96%BA%E1%98%8E%E1%95%8A and favorited by some one also.

Comment: Also reported less explicitly here: [The Authentication Problem of WebAuthenticationBroke Classr in .NET 4.6](http://stackapps.com/q/6887) (seeing if someone reported the problem earlier for duping)

Comment: @BrockAdams You can reproduce by trying to get an access token from the API console while not logged in, not sure if there's an earlier report of this or not

Comment: @TimStone, I verified that I can authenticate just fine both from my applications and from the API livedocs.  Also, [the bug that you may be referencing](http://stackapps.com/questions/6166/resurfacing-bug-could-not-parse-proxy-url-error-message) always gave an error and seems to have been ninja-fixed in the last year anyway.  The OP has failed to provide a recipe for this bug and maybe also omitted crucial error messages.

Comment: The only other "First time" bugs were fixed long ago and not reoccurring now (in my spot checks).  See http://stackapps.com/questions/3156/oauth-redirect-not-completing and linked question.

Comment: @BrockAdams Were you already authenticated by the site? I can easily reproduce if I have to log into Google or the SE OpenID. The process takes you just to `http://stackexchange.com/#`, like is shown in the screenshot from the first linked question (here's [my attempt](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UTfG9.png))

Comment: @TimStone, I tried it both ways (pre-authenticated and unauthenticated) x 3 different approaches (docs, implicit app, explicit app). I don't use Google however.  Since you have a recipe to duplicate, maybe edit that into the question?

Comment: @TimStone Okay, verified that http://stackapps.com/questions/6166/resurfacing-bug-could-not-parse-proxy-url-error-message is NOT fixed.  This question is the exact same problem, minus the helpful error message that the duplicate question included.